# MySQL - Alternative to GROUP BY without aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

Imagine an unordered table set up as below:

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| ID |  Project   | Resource | StartDate |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | ExtraParts | Mark     | 24/01     |
|  2 | ExtraParts | Sam      | 22/01     |
|  3 | TimeLabour | Sally    | 19/01     |
|  4 | TimeLabour | Sarena   | 23/01     |
|  5 | Runway     | Olly     | 14/02     |
|  6 | Runway     | Mary     | 14/05     |
+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to order by the earliest StartDate for each project, but still group the resources from each projects together(not sure if im explaining this right, but below is what I would like to achieve)

```
    +----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID |  Project    | Resource  | StartDate |
+----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | TimeLabor   | Sally     | 19/01     |
|  2 | TimeLabor   | Sarena    | 23/01     |
|  3 | ExtraParts  | Sam       | 22/01     |
|  4 | ExtraParts  | Mark      | 24/01     |
|  5 | Runway      | Olly      | 14/02     |
|  6 | Runway      | Mary      | 14/05     |
+----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

If I do ORDER BY StartDate, Project then the result will have jumbled up the projects. If i ORDER BY Project, StartDate  then the result will be sorted alphabetically by project first and then sort by date within the same project(if that makes sense). As stated above, I would like to order by the earliest StartDate for each project while still grouping the projects together(not aggregate grouping, just one under the other).

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this? [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ff7a/1) to play with

```
SELECT project, resource, startdate
FROM testing
ORDER BY project, STR_TO_DATE(StartDate, '%d/%m')
```

basically your table is storing dates as a string and in order for you to order it you need to convert the strings to recognized dates... so the STR_TO_DATE() is a method to do that :)

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for your suggestion. My bad what I typed up above was just an example, my DB is storing dates properly(yyyy-mm-dd).

ORDER BY Project, DATE lists projects in alphabetical order, and then orders by date. I.E project "Runway" would be first

Comment: so what does the actual data look like? i can't help you if I dont know what the date format is :)

Comment: @user3792362 also did you look at the sql fiddle? is this output not what you want? http://screencast.com/t/LHioTzxOux

Comment: Hey John. The actual data looks exactly like above. But the StartDate column is of type date in MySQL and not varchar. 

Also , the output I am after is in the second table in my intiail post ^^^. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user3792362 Oh ok i understand now.. do you have ID's that are for each row in the database?

Comment: Yep they do. I have updated the table in the intial question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the date used for the ordering:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select project, min(startdate) as minsd
      from table t
      group by project
     ) tp
     on t.project = tp.project
order by tp.minsd, t.project;
```

Note:  this assumes that `startdate` is really stored as a date and not a string.  If it is stored as a string, then you should convert it to a date first.